# How to install mencode with libmp3lame support on a mac?

Tags: mac, video, ffmpeg

On a mac (OS 10.13.6) I like to convert a video file with `mencoder` as follows:

```
mencoder input.mkv -sub subtitle.srt -o output.avi -oac mp3lame -ovc x264
```

However, I get the error message:

```
MEncoder 1.3.0-4.2.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
MPlayer was compiled without libmp3lame support.
```

How to install/compile mplayer/mencoder to get this command working.

I appreciate a detailed step-by-step description of each step, describing exactly what to do.